# Mainboard beeping for error but running fine - beep codes corrupt?

Tags: motherboard, bios, hardware-failure, desktop-computer

I traded CPU, PSU and Graphics Card with a friend. When I took his parts and build my PC everything works fine. When We tried to put my parts in his PC, the Mainboard did a non-ending 2 tone siren alarm (long - short). We did many things to see whats wrong, and we thought the MB is dead.

Now, half a year later, my MB is dead. I forgot about what we thought about his MB a few months ago, so I tried to pull back all his parts in the "original" PC. Everything works. For me it's obvious that my MB is dead. But his MB is now behaving weird.

When I start the PC MB beeps once short, and works fine. When I
**restart the PC** in Windows 7 or Windows 8.1 the PC restarts and beeps
long-short once on startup. Its the same sound like in the past, when
nothing worked, but only once.

**Short clip on Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ujvJUScexVw**

**Mainboard:** Abit IP35V
**CPU:** Intel Core 2 Quad Q9450
**RAM:** 4x2GB Kingston Hyper X DDR2 8500-CL5 1066MHz
**PSU:** BeQuiet 550W
**Graphics Card:** nVidia GeForce GTX 285 AMP OC

I did BIOS Update successfully and I cleared CMOS a few times. Still same problem. **I'm wondering because the PC looks like it is running fine. But why the long-short beep on restart?**

Is it possible that just the beep-code part on a MB is corrupt? Anyway, I hope some of you got some ideas to help me out. I don't got the finances to get a new PC, I could only ask my friend to get his Abit Board and then I have to hope it will stay alive one more year. Other MB on same level costs 80€ (new). I don't want to investigate that much.

Comment: In your research what does the error code mean?

Comment: never had that problem, but it sounds to me like it is two-tone siren Low CPU Fan speed or Voltage Level issue. Maybe you should check that

Comment: Does this help ? http://superuser.com/questions/797012/why-does-my-computer-beep-when-i-turn-it-on-what-are-these-beep-codes

Comment: {at} Ramhound My research said in the past "A two-tone siren, generally caused by overheating or out of specification voltages", now I got the same sound but only once. 1 long - 1 short means "DRAM ERROR". I checked my RAM, it works fine in several PCs. @malakrsnaslava I checkes PSU too, no PSU problem. I never configured anything besides boot priority in BIOS, I have to do some research about what should be and what is. I'm at home in around 5-6 hours, I can upload a screenshot tho.

Comment: Your memory working in another system doesn't indicate there isn't a problem with the motherboard's memory modules  If the system will not even POST, and you have decoded the error code, then the meaning of the code is your answer.  If it does POST use memtestx86 to verify any memory problems.

Comment: @Ramhound Yeah I already thought about this, but remember, this only happens on restart. Not on powering on. That's what making me thinking it shouldn't be a memory slot problem too...but at least I know it does the same with other RAM too ...

Comment: @Dave like you can read in the comments above, I got some sources too, but this doesn't really helps me, because I'm not sure if the beeps are right...

Comment: I totally glazed over the "restart" aspect because you quoted that text.  It really wasn't necessary to do that.

Comment: @malakrsnaslava sry missed the source: http://www.overclockers.com/forums/showthread.php/218664-ABIT-BIOS-BEEP-CODES {at}Ramhound sorry for that :/

Comment: @Ramhound Did memtest again on boot http://postimg.org/image/b98fj8y1b/

Comment: My Temperatures http://postimg.org/image/7ig1m7p3h/