# Laptop boots to black screen with four beeps

Tags: boot, laptop, dell-inspiron

Dell Inspiron 15 model 3537 laptop.

When turning on the laptop, the system boots to a black screen with four beeps. The problem persists on a restart, and pressing F12 or any other key does not help. However, the power light is lit and the fan is running.

What should I do?

Comment: [What are these beep codes?](http://superuser.com/questions/797012/why-does-my-computer-beep-when-i-turn-it-on-what-are-these-beep-codes)

Answer (score 4):

Each BIOS manufacturer uses a unique series of diagnostic beeps during the Power On Self Test to identify various hardware problems.  On your computer, **four beeps indicates a memory failure**.

- Open the service cover on your laptop and make sure your memory is properly seated. Try removing and reinserting the memory modules. If you have compatible memory modules, try replacing the supplied modules with them. If these steps don't address your problem, your computer may need to be repaired by a technician. **See: [Dell Inspiron 3537 troubleshooting page](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN179175/EN#Issue0_15)**
- To install a laptop memory module (SO-DIMM), insert the module at an angle into the slot and push it down to lock it in. To remove a module, pull on the two side clips that hold the module; this will cause the module to pop up for removal. Be sure to ground yourself to prevent damage from electrostatic discharge. **See: [LAPTOP Magazine guide on upgrading RAM](http://blog.laptopmag.com/ram-upgrade-tutorial)**

[image: Installing laptop memory]
*Installing an SO-DIMM into a laptop ([source](http://blog.laptopmag.com/ram-upgrade-tutorial))*

Comment: If it is a **memory subsystem problem**, then chances are high that the user data on the HD can be recovered, so at least @chrissy can recover the files.