# 9 beeps when the Lenovo Thinkcenter M58 PC Start

Tags: motherboard, thinkcentre

I was trying to fix a problem with an old Thinkcenter M58 PC that makes the fan either working an full or at the lowest speed (depending on the occupied ram slot) I have tried to remove nearly every caple from the mother board , make CLR_CMOS and CLR_CMOSHW reset at the motherboard , changing some bois options , Put i have failed and give-up , Now i have a new more serious problem and dont know what make it appear , When I try to start the PC after a shutdown or make a system restart , after about 1 second and before the bios screen appear i hear 9 fast beeps (3 beeps - short silence - 3 beeps - short silence -3 beeps) then the screen turn off , i can hear the PC is still running but noting happen .

After i press the turn off button for 5 seconds the computer shutdown , then pressing the turnoff button again the computer starts normally and so on !!

So I think the hardware is functioning normally , but having to do this every time i turn on the PC is so irritating and noisy , and it wasn't like that when i started fixing the fan problem !

PC : Thinkcenter M58p
Motherboard : LENOVO (LGA 775)
Bios : LENOVO 5CKT77AUS
Operating System : Windows Xp Pro
Chip Model : Intel Q45/Q43

---

Edit:

---

May be i was wrong , I have flashed the Bios again from inside the Windows < i have disabled all the checks so i can flash the same version again , Now the beeps changed I can hear 16 beep (4-4-4-4) , also pressing enter to get the list of options inside the bios is no longer working , I have managed to enter using F1 , found the following at the main page : Machine type/Model : INVALID , System Serial Number : INVALID , UUID : ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff

---

I Canot find this beep code neither at the Thinkcenter M58 Manual posted by DavidPostill nor at the link posted by Dave .

---

I have tried Using the Setup Utility to load defaults and then press F10 to Save and exit but nothing changed , although i can still log into the windows after the second restart .

---

I will try to Perform a Boot-block recovery as per the manual then post the result again , thanks for the help .

Comment: Does this help http://superuser.com/questions/797012/why-does-my-computer-beep-when-i-turn-it-on-what-are-these-beep-codes

Comment: You sure about those duration and number of beeps?  [Looking at general Lenovo documentation that does not appear to be valid.  of course Thinkpad and Thinkcenter are separate families.](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/ht035729).  When Lenovo was contacted what did they see the beep codes meant?

Comment: Here are the beep codes for Thinkcenter M58 http://www.manualslib.com/manual/290920/Lenovo-Thinkcentre-M58-9960.html?page=82#manual. None of them match your description.

Comment: The nearest is 1 long and 9 short beeps
BIOS ROM error

Comment: Perform the following actions in order.
1. Start the Setup Utility program and press
F9 to load defaults and then press F10 to
Save and exit. See Chapter 6, "Using the
Setup Utility," on page 49.
2. Perform a Boot-block recovery. See
"Recovering from a POST/BIOS update
failure" on page 762.
3. Replace the system board.

Comment: What is meant by "insert the POST/BIOS update (flash update) disc into the optical drive" at the Guide ? where I can find the image for this Disk ? Is it the Flash BIOS update (CD ISO image version) iso 3.13 MB found here http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds013586 ?

Comment: I hope any one will answer my question as i am stuck at this step now

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same 3 times the 3 beeps and what it seemed to fix the problem was the following:

With the computer turned off I have taken the memory off and put them back on. Turn the computer back on and there was no beep. It boot up as normal. I have rebooted the computer and it still boots up normally. I shall keep you posted if anything changes.