# HP Pavillion m9775fr - short beep - long beep - pause - repeating at power on

Tags: boot, motherboard, desktop-computer, hp-pavilion, system-sounds

I own this computer for some years now, it was working great. But today, I cannot start it anymore.
It's a HP Pavillion, Model m9775frProduct# VD052AA-ABF
On the motherboard I see: IPIEL-LA3 rev 1.01

Now, when I click on the power on button:
-The screen remains black
-The sound sequence :"short beep - long beep - pause" is repeating until i power off the machine.

What happened? I never hack its hardware, I don't understand...

Thank you for your answers

Edit: It's not a duplicate of the suggested post because in this case, it's a HP BIOS, which is not covered by the suggested duplicate question

Comment: Google "HP pavilion beep codes"... I tried to look up the meaning of short long for you, but the article cautions they can vary by bios version and there is no enough info in your question to get past that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my computer beep when I turn it on? What are these beep codes?](http://superuser.com/questions/797012/why-does-my-computer-beep-when-i-turn-it-on-what-are-these-beep-codes) .. I guess a motherboard issue

Answer (score 0):

I found HP beep codes here:

HP and Compaq All-in-One and HP TouchSmart Desktop PCs - BIOS Beep Codes
http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02222922

Comment: The code means: memory problem. I checked my memory by removing the 4 RAM modules that were plugged to check which one was faulty. Result: witn no RAM module plugged i still get the same beep code...