# Toshiba p300 2TB internal drive, meaning of 6 beeps?

Tags: sata, toshiba-hard-drive

I've just purchased a toshiba P300 internal 2TB sata hard drive.

However I'm getting 6 beeps, what does this mean?

Also there 2 pins rather than 4, couldn't this need a jumper?

[image]

Here's a video showing the 6 beeps / noises 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/safnkf9usqsysqb/Video%2012-08-2017%2C%2007%2030%2002.mov?dl=0

Comment: When do the beeps occur? Does your computer boot at all? Different BIOS vendors use different beep codes. Look up yours [here](https://www.computerhope.com/beep.htm). Which cable has 2 pins instead of 4? SATA interface cables don't really have "pins". Can you provide a picture of the pins you mean?

Comment: It's the drive that beeps. The pins are to the right of the power connector

Comment: Added picture to question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my computer beep when I turn it on? What are these beep codes?](https://superuser.com/questions/797012/why-does-my-computer-beep-when-i-turn-it-on-what-are-these-beep-codes)

Comment: I have the drive in a caddy / also tried in a docking station, which I have plugged into my Mac books USB port. It's not the bios which beeps. It's the drive itself. When I say beeps, it more like hard drive noises which are identical and occur 6 times.

Comment: Have attached video with the noises

Comment: Hard drives don't have speakers and thus cannot "beep". They can make noise because they are mechanical. The noises can indicate things, but there is not a "code" of hard drive sounds used to indicate status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't sound normal. If the drive doesn't appear in Disk Utility (and you're sure the caddy you're using works), it's probably defective, and should be returned.

Leave the pins alone. They aren't a standard part of the SATA connector --
 they may be part of an internal programming or debugging interface.

Comment: It doesn't appear on my Mac, unlike my other drives. It seems like the pins are for a connector or a jumper.