# My Gigabyte motherboard keeps beeping

Tags: audio, motherboard

I have a Gigabyte motherboard, it keeps beeping constantly. Everything works but I'm worried that the sound is warning me about something. What could that be? The computer works fine, I'm just worried about the sound.

Specs:

- Gigabyte GA-EP45-UD3L
- Pentium 4, 3.00 GHz, 2MB
- NVidia GeForce GTX 560 TI
- 3 GB RAM, DDR2

Comment: The beep you're hearing is a POST alert. Count the beeps, then look up the fault codes for your bios type. It'll either be an issue with the RAM, CPU, CPU power or GPU. Very odd that it boots though. Alternatively, you have your PC speaker connected to the wrong terminal.

Comment: i started the computer, it works fine. gb ram is 3 as it is inserted. cpu is fine cpu fan is fine too, gpu is fine,.

Comment: Are you hearing the beeps from the internal PC speaker in the case? Or through your speakers via the 3.5mm jack?

Comment: pc speaker in the case (the one inserted in motherboard)

Comment: Unplug it then... or swap the connector round; you might have the polarity wrong.

Comment: i did unplug it, no more sound. and i swaped them alr before

Comment: Then we're all good :) Might be worth checking device manager for any rogue devices, or perform a CPU/RAM test just to check everything is OK.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my computer beep when I turn it on? What are these beep codes?](https://superuser.com/questions/797012/why-does-my-computer-beep-when-i-turn-it-on-what-are-these-beep-codes)

Comment: POST codes only play when the computer is first started. Beeps while the computer is running are different. @MarwanDaloub, please confirm if the beeps only happen when the computer first starts, before Windows loads, or if you can hear them while the OS is running and you are using the computer.

Comment: @spikey_richie, POST stands for Power On Self Test. POST codes ONLY play when the computer is first started. If the beeps sounds at any time after boot, they are, by definition, not POST codes.

Comment: I know what POST stands for, and what it means. Don't try and school me in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause: the fan wasn't installed perfectly, so the CPU got to about 60-80 ℃ and then the motherboard was beeping.