# Lenovo ThinkCentre: beeps when trying to restart

Tags: hardware-failure, lenovo-desktop-computer

We have a Lenovo ThinkCentre, brand new, that has on occasion failed to start when trying to restart. It simply gives off loud beeps, that I suppose have meaning: 1 long and 3 short. There is nothing on the screen. After holding the power button until it shuts down, then starting it again, it works fine. We experience no other performance issues.

I do not know enough about computer hardware to know what to check/troubleshoot, etc. C̶a̶n̶ ̶a̶n̶y̶o̶n̶e̶ ̶g̶i̶v̶e̶ ̶t̶i̶p̶s̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶f̶i̶g̶u̶r̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶o̶u̶t̶ ̶w̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶b̶e̶e̶p̶s̶ ̶m̶e̶a̶n̶,̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶o̶t̶h̶e̶r̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶n̶g̶s̶ ̶I̶ ̶c̶a̶n̶ ̶d̶o̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶n̶a̶r̶r̶o̶w̶ ̶d̶o̶w̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶i̶s̶s̶u̶e̶?̶

Signs seem to point to issues with the RAM. I have reseated the RAM. Since then, it has never failed to start.

**Specifications:**

- Lenovo ThinkCentre M700 Signature Edition
- Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6500 CPU @ 3.20GHz 3.19 GHz
- 8.00 GB RAM
- 64-bit OS-- Windows 10 Pro
- 1- 1 TB HDD
- 1- 256 GB SSD
- Anything more needed?

Comment: Make sure the 8 GB RAM sticks are seated correctly.

Comment: I did this (took out the stick, it seemed well seated, and put it firmly back in), so now it is just -- wait and see if it does it again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/797012/why-does-my-computer-beep-when-i-turn-it-on-what-are-these-beep-codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what the lenovo beep codes are

https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht035729 and https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht062270

based on the second link it might be memory related.

Comment: I reseated the memory, now I will keep an eye on it. It does not fail every time I boot it.